# We should strive for consistent spelling forms

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

I just noted that the [palaeobotany](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palaeobotany) is using british spelling, while all the other similar tags are using american spelling (e.g. [paleontology](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paleontology). As a community, we should strive for tags using the same spelling forms, so that they have a logical consistency. At the moment I do not have the reputation to edit or retag the relevant questions, but maybe one of the moderators could take a look at this.

Comment: [British](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/British#Adjective) and [American](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/American#Adjective) it is.

Comment: If you can put together a list of tags that are British-spelt and what the American-spelt equivalents are I can create some synonyms.

Comment: I've gone ahead and merged & synonymized [tag:palaeobotany] into [tag:paleobotany].

Comment: @casey I will try to do that later when I have the time. Right now, I don't know if there are many of these cases in the created tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been discussed on [the mother meta before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us).

The bottom line then, was:

- posters are free to write in their own dialect of English
- but tagging should be in American English.

The British-spelt tags can be made synonyms of the American-spelt tags